# How do you average hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds? E.g How do you divide a timestamp by an integer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Give a timestamp in the format of `hh:mm:ss.SSS`, how do you divide this timestamp by an integer and get a timestamp as the result?

For example, given a timestamp of `00:03:00:090`, if I divide this by `3`, I would expect to get a timestamp of `00:01:00:030`.

If I had a timestamp of `00:05:35:100` and divide it by `3`, I would expect `00:01:51:700` as a result. If I divided by `2`, I would expect `00:02:47:550` as a result.

```js
     $(window).on("load", function() {
          $('#Btn_Calculate_Average').click(function (e) { 
               e.preventDefault();
               
               Average();
          });

         function Average(){
               let in_Time = $('#in_Time').val();
               let in_valueSelected = $('#in_valueSelected').val();

               var Average = in_Time / in_valueSelected;

               $('#in_Result').val(Average);
         }
          
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
               <div class="Dv">
                    <label for="in_Time">Time</label>
                    <input type="text" id="in_Time" value="00:05:35:100" >
               </div>

               <label  for="in_valueSelected">Divide By:</label>
               <input   name="in_valueSelected" id="in_Média"  type="text" value="3" list="lsit_valueSelected">
               <datalist id="lsit_valueSelected">
                    <option value="1">
                    <option value="2">
                    <option value="3">
                    <option value="4">
                    <option value="5">
                    <option value="6">
                    <option value="7">
               </datalist>
              
               <button id="Btn_Calculate_Average">Calculate Average</button>

               <div class="Dv">
                    <label for="in_Result">Media</label>
                    <input type="text" id="in_Result" value="" >
               </div>
          </div>
```

***Resolution***

```js
$(window).on("load", function () {
               const toMilliseconds = (timestamp) => {
                    let [hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds] = timestamp.split(':')
                    hours = +hours
                    minutes = +minutes
                    seconds = +seconds
                    milliseconds = +milliseconds
                    console.log(hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
                    return (hours * 3.6e6) + (minutes * 60000) + (seconds * 1000) + milliseconds
               }
               const toTimestamp = (ms) => {
                    const hours = Math.floor(ms / 3.6e6)
                    ms = ms % 3.6e6
                    const minutes = Math.floor(ms / 60000)
                    ms = ms % 60000
                    const seconds = Math.floor(ms / 1000)
                    ms = ms % 1000
                    return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}:${ms}`
               }
               // var in_Time = $('#in_Time').val();
               // let in_valueSelected = $('#in_valueSelected').val();
               $('#Btn_Calculate_Average').click(function (e) {

                    var ResultadoDaMedia =  toTimestamp(toMilliseconds($('#in_Time').val()) / $('#in_valueSelected').val())

                    $('#in_Result').val(ResultadoDaMedia)
                    console.log(ResultadoDaMedia)
               })
               // var DIVISER = 
               // input.addEventListener('input', e => {
               //           console.log(output.textContent = toTimestamp(toMilliseconds(input.value) / 2));
               // }) 
          });
```

```css
body {
     background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
     margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
     height: 100vh; width: 100%;
     display: flex; flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center; justify-content: flex-start;
     overflow: scroll;
}


.container {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    margin: 5px; padding: 5px;
    min-height: 500px; width: 100%;
    max-height: 64px;
    display: flex; flex-direction: column;
    align-items:center; justify-content: flex-start;
    overflow: scroll;

}
.Dv {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    margin: 5px; padding:10px;
    height: auto; width: 100%;
    display: flex; flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center; justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden; 

}



label, button{
     margin: 4px;

}

input {
     margin: 4px;
     max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
          <div class="Dv">
               <label for="in_Time">Time</label>
               <input type="text" id="in_Time" value="00:05:35:100">
          </div>

          <label for="in_valueSelected">Divide By:</label>
          <input name="in_valueSelected" id="in_valueSelected" type="text" list="lsit_valueSelected">
          <datalist id="lsit_valueSelected">
               <option value="1">
               <option value="2">
               <option value="3">
               <option value="4">
               <option value="5">
               <option value="6">
               <option value="7">
          </datalist>

          <button id="Btn_Calculate_Average">Calculate Average</button>

          <div class="Dv">
               <label for="in_Result">Media</label>
               <input type="text" id="in_Result" value="">
          </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: you turn `in_Time` into milliseconds divide by `in_valueSelected` and then recalculate hours, minutes, seconds, ms and set `in_Result`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, one way to accomplish this would be to convert the time to the smallest unit (milliseconds, in this case), then divide by whatever number, then convert back to a timestamp:

```js
const toMilliseconds = (timestamp) => {
  let [
    hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds
  ] = timestamp.split(':')
  hours = +hours
  minutes = +minutes
  seconds = +seconds
  milliseconds = +milliseconds
  return (hours * 3.6e6)
    + (minutes * 60000)
    + (seconds * 1000)
    + milliseconds
}

const toTimestamp = (ms) => {
  const hours = ('' + Math.floor(ms / 3.6e6)).padStart(2, '0')
  ms = ms % 3.6e6
  const minutes = ('' + Math.floor(ms / 60000)).padStart(2, '0')
  ms = ms % 60000
  const seconds = ('' + Math.floor(ms / 1000)).padStart(2, '0')
  ms = ('' + Math.floor(ms % 1000)).padStart(3, '0')
  return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}:${ms}`
}

const average = (timestamp, diviser) => {
  return toTimestamp( toMilliseconds(timestamp) / diviser )
}

const input = document.querySelector('#input')
const output = document.querySelector('#output')

const DIVISER = 3
input.addEventListener('input', e => {
  output.textContent = average(input.value, DIVISER)
})
```

```html
<input id="input" />
<div id="output" />
```